# Python: PIL/_imaging.so: invalid ELF header

Tags: python, web, virtualenv, python-imaging-library

I'm using a virtualenv to run Python 2.7 in my local machine and everything works as expected. When I transfer "site-packages" to my production sever, I get the follow error:

```
PIL/_imaging.so: invalid ELF header
```

This happens on the Pillow 2.5.3 pypi package found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.5.3)

I am running OS X, while my production server is running Debian. I suspect the OS differences might be causing the issue but I'm not sure. I have no idea how to fix this. Can anyone help?

Note: I cannot install packages directly to my production server, so I have to upload them directly to use them.

Comment: You cannot just transfer `site-packages` to another server with a different architecture. *Rebuild the virtual env instead*. OS X handles shared libraries *entirely differently* from Linux.

Answer (score 2):

In your current virtual environment, execute the following command

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Copy this `requirements.txt` file to your server.

Create your new virtualenvironment (delete the one you were using before).

Activate the virtual environment and then type `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Now, the libraries will be installed correctly and built accurately as well.

If you see errors for PIL, execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev
sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging
```

virtual environments are for isolating Python on your current machine; they are not for creating portable environments. The benefit is to work with different versions of Python packages without modifying the system Python installation.

Using virtual environments does not require super-user permissions; so you can install packages even if you are not "root".

It does, however, require Internet access as packages are downloaded from the web. If your server does not have access to the Internet, back on your mac, do the following, from your virtual environment:

```
pip install basket
```

This will install [`basket`](http://pythonhosted.org//Basket/) which is a small utility that allows you to download packages *but not install them*. Great for keeping a local archive of packages that you can move to other machines.

Once its installed, follow these steps as listed in the documentation:

1. `basket init`
2. `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
3. `awk -F'==' '{print $1}' requirements.txt | basket download`

This will download all the packages from your requirements.txt file into `~/.basket`

Next, copy this directory to your server and then run the following command from your virtualenvironment

`pip install --no-index -f /path/to/basket -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the command line? Unfortunately I'm on a shared host that does not provide a native utility for python package installs.